# Initialise fastapi web service fully before listening on port

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, fastapi, google-cloud-run

I have a fastapi web app which is running inside of a docker container. The web app hosts multiple machine learning models which on startup it needs to read into memory. This process can take around 30 seconds.

What I am trying to achieve is to have the container startup and load all the models, classes etc before listening to any requests. This is useful because on platforms such as Google Cloud Run, you have a max of 4 minutes of startup before your container must start listening to traffic. Right now my container will drop any traffic whilst it is in this startup mode.

I was wondering if there was a way to achieve this either with some docker or fastapi magic!

Comment: Can you make the loading of models async? Then the startup would be fast, but you could put in an app level dependency that would check if loading is done or not and raises accordingly?

Comment: That is quite the opposite of what I would like to do (unless I misunderstood you). The models are read from disk, not over a network, so async is no help here I believe. I want the service to first spend time loading the models and only then to signify it is ready for handling traffic.

Comment: apologies, I misunderstood what you are trying to achieve, ignore my previous comment!

Comment: It's an interesting question and I've not had cause to need to solve for something like this. I think the solution would be to rely upon HTTP response codes and have your service respond with 503 (unavailable) until it's ready to serve requests.Clients should retry requests until it becomes available. Be mindful that Cloud Run will scale down instances after non-use. If you want to avoid repeated restarts, you'll want to consider keeping a minimum number of instances running (which will incur cost).

Comment: You may want to consider decomposing the app into a frontend and separate processes to host the models. This way you can scale|deploy the frontend and models independently.

Comment: @DazWilkin I do think you are correct - this is what I have been thinking about for some time, but will require a large refactor. Do you have any references, or tools which help with such an architecture?

Comment: It's difficult (and discouraged by Stack overflow) to provide architectural guidance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is possible with FastAPI magic! In both solutions presented, FastAPI will not start serving requests until the startup logic (in your case, loading a ML model) completes.

In practice, the app won't start listening on the selected port until the startup logic is complete and since you're running your app on the Google Cloud Run platform, it won't serve traffic to your app until it then.

**If you're using FastAPI version < `0.93.0`**:

You should load your model in the "startup event handler". Example:

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI


def fake_answer_to_everything_ml_model(x: float):
    return True


ml_models = {}

app = FastAPI()

@app.on_event("startup")
async def app_startup():
    # Load your ML model:
    ml_models["answer_to_everything"] = fake_answer_to_everything_ml_model
```

**If you're using FastAPI version >= `0.93.0`:**

You should define your startup logic using the lifespan parameter of the FastAPI app. More comprehensive documentation can be found [here](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/events/), I'll just show a minimal example:

```py
from contextlib import asynccontextmanager

from fastapi import FastAPI


def fake_answer_to_everything_ml_model(x: float):
    return True


ml_models = {}


@asynccontextmanager
async def lifespan(app: FastAPI):
    # Load your ML model
    ml_models["answer_to_everything"] = fake_answer_to_everything_ml_model
    yield
    # If you want you can define your shutdown logic after the `yield` keyword.


app = FastAPI(lifespan=lifespan)
```